# How can i disable specific and multiple date calendars in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, datepickerdialog

I am Using DatePickerDialog. but not showing setDisabledDays. so how is it possible in kotlin. My required is multiple dates disable and also one max and min range of calendar

fun datepicker(){

```
        val year = calendarNow.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val month = calendarNow.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val day = calendarNow.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(this,
            { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
               //my code
            }, year, month, day
        )
        datePickerDialog.datePicker.setMinDate(milliseconds)
        //val days = arrayOf<Calendar>(2023-08-22, 2023-08-12, 2023-08-15) //this is disable dates
        //datePickerDialog.setDisabledDays() //this line is not working how to solved this
        datePickerDialog.show()
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this "MaterialDateTimePicker" library, which provides enhanced features including the ability to disable specific dates and Min & Max Years and many more...

Here's how you can use the "MaterialDateTimePicker" library to disable specific dates:

1. Add the library to your app's build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:4.2.3'
```

2. Use the library in your code:

```kotlin
  fun datepicker() {
        val disabledDays = arrayOf(
            Calendar.getInstance().apply {
                set(Calendar.YEAR, 2023)
                set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.AUGUST)
                set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 22)
            },
            Calendar.getInstance().apply {
                set(Calendar.YEAR, 2023)
                set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.AUGUST)
                set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 12)
            },
            Calendar.getInstance().apply {
                set(Calendar.YEAR, 2023)
                set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.AUGUST)
                set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 15)
            }
        )

        val now = Calendar.getInstance()
        val minYear = 2023
        val maxYear = 2023
        val minMonth = Calendar.JANUARY // 0-based index
        val maxMonth = Calendar.DECEMBER // 0-based index
        val minDay = 1
        val maxDay = 25

        val dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
            OnDateSetListener { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
                // Handle selected date
            },
            now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        )

        dpd.setDisabledDays(disabledDays)
        dpd.setMinDate(Calendar.getInstance().apply {
            set(minYear, minMonth, minDay)
        })
        dpd.setMaxDate(Calendar.getInstance().apply {
            set(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay)
        })

        dpd.show(supportFragmentManager, "DatePickerDialog")
    }
```

In this example, i'm using the "MaterialDateTimePicker" library to create a date picker dialog. We've set the `disabledDays` array with specific dates that you want to disable and min max years.

---

**Library:** [MaterialDateTimePicker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) in case you want to see more about it.

Comment: Please vote up if this it the answer of your problem. Thanks